# Updating a specific record in the database?

Tags: javascript, database, record, app-lab

I'm using Javascript with applab. The code creates new users fine, but it only updates the first record. Any ideas how to fix this so that it will update for each new and returning user? I think I need to use a math function with "mostRecentID" or  "record.ID" to achieve this.
Link to Project: https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/bSkJw2auZx8Iq7ZGemsT7HwQrOVBWFPl6eLl0R0a6VU If you go to "how it works (view code)", and then you can see the code and the database.

```
//The database for this code already exists.
//This code creates new users fine, but it only updates the first record.
//What code will update a specific ID in the database 
//I think I need to use a math function with "mostRecentID" or  "record.ID" to achieve this.
var mostRecentID=1;
var player = {};
var UserID = getUserId();
onEvent("addNewRecordButton", "click", function() {
  readRecords("AllUserData", player, function(records) {
      var count = records.length;
      if (count > 1) {
          
      } else if ((count == 1)) {
          
      } else {
          var player = {};
          player.UserID = getUserId();
          player.Username=getText("usernameInput");
          createRecord("AllUserData", player, function(record) {
              mostRecentID=record.id;
          });
      }
  });
});
onEvent("updateInformationButton", "click", function() {
  updateRecord("AllUserData", {id:mostRecentID,UserID:getUserId(),Username:(getText("usernameInput"))}, function() {
    
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, not at an external link.

Comment: @Phineas it's not the correct way, instead you can try adding a dropdown where user can select which one he wants to edit

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you wanted to update a record matching the current user's user ID. You would need to specify the user ID in the parameters object.

```
readRecords("AllUserData", {UserID: getUserId()}, function (records) {
  if (records.length > 0) {
    updateRecord("AllUserData", {id: records[0].id, UserID:getUserId(),Username:(getText("usernameInput"))}, function () {
      // callback code
    });
  } else {
    createRecord("AllUserData", {UserID:getUserId(),Username:(getText("usernameInput"))}, function () {
      // callback code
    });
  }
});
```